# About width in IE7

Tags: css

I have this [site](http://www.canalonesbastimar.com). As you can see using IE7 the width of the `header` is widther than the content below, I mean It does not have `width: 960px` as I expected. Could you tell me why?

This is the code of the `header` tag:

```
header {
  border-top: 6px solid #9F9F9F;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: $amarillo;
  width: 960px;
  padding: 19px 34px;
}
```

Comment: Please read this, and add the info to your question. Don't link to your site. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Comment: When you're having problems with things lining-up, remove the padding and margin for the axis you're having a hard time with. Padding can be tricky when debugging layout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<header>` is an unknown element for IE7.

For all html5 issues, you can use [html5shiv](https://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/).

Comment: I could be mistaken but aren't any unknown tags treated as `<div />` tags in old IE?

Comment: Not in IE7. Remember at that time, the browser is designed according to the HTML4 standard. Different browser treat unknown tags differently. IE7 goes the stringent way and ignore them.

Comment: Gotcha, that's too bad. It's nice how the HTML5 doctype works for old browses.

Comment: If you use a modern version of IE to check your webpage using IE7 compatibility mode, look at the HTML tab, and you will find your `<header>` is displayed as `<header/>`, losing all the content inside.

Comment: Generally, html5shiv and modernizr are must-have's if we need to support old IE browsers.

Comment: @Blaise you said "If you use a modern version of IE to check your webpage using IE7 compatibility mode..", what do you mean exactly? Is there any way to check the result in IE7, using IE 9 or 10?

Comment: hit `f12` to bring out the dev tool

Answer (score 1):

Elements like `header`, `nav`, `footer`, `article`, `section` and so forth are not supported in IE7.  You need to use the [HTML5shiv](https://code.google.com/p/html5shim/) or similar as a polyfill.

Also, in the default box model `border-box` padding is added to width for total element width, so your element is 960px + 34px + 34px, not just 960px.  Apply the property `box-sizing: content-box` if you want `padding` to be subtracted from the `width` rather than added to it.